# How to get object result set from JDBC Sampler in JMeter Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am having trouble getting the result set object from JDBC Sampler in JMeter.   The JMeter documentation says this exactly:

```
Result Variable Name
If specified, this will create an Object variable containing a list of
    row maps. Each map contains the column name as the key and the column 
    data as the value. 
Usage:
  columnValue = vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0).get("Column Name");
```

So, I configured it like that and it works.  But since the document above says that I creates a "list of row maps", I thought I would try to create a List object from it in BeanShell to make it more readable.  I tried doing this but it didn't work.   Does anyone know the answer?

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> results = vars.getObject("resultList");
```

And the error is more or less something like this:

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh 
 method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of:
 ``List<Map<String,Integer>> results = vars.getObject("resultList")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beanshell is not Java, you need to access it a little bit differently.

Those "diamond" brackets are not very supported by Beanshell. Please amend your code as follows:

```
ArrayList result = vars.getObject("resultList");
for (HashMap table : result) {
    for (Object column : table.keySet()) {
        log.info(column + "=" + table.get(column));
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that you have set `resultList` as a "Result Variable Name" in your JDBC Request Sampler.

That should print query result into *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details and kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Comment: Yes, that definitely worked beautifully.  Thank you!