# How to use Result Variable Name of Jdbc Request in Bean Shell post processor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am using jdbc request in jmeter. I want to use result of select query as a variable so i can perform some operation in beanshell postprocessor. My sql query is-

```
select * from table where id = 11111 and number = ${num} order by id desc limit 1;
```

I used ResultSet as a Result variable name. How can i use it in beanshell processor.
And can i use this variable in other sampler?

**Plz help. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Check the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969792/how-to-get-object-result-set-from-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter

Answer (score 5):

You can access it as simple as `vars.getObject("ResultSet");` which will return an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with query results.

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class. See JavaDoc on above classes to see what you can do with them and what is the most useful in your case. Also it worth checking out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Another option is defining "Variable Names" field as

```
column1,column2,column3
```

So you will be able to access row values as:

```
vars.get("column1_1"); //for first row of column1
vars.get("column2_1"); //for first row of column2
vars.get("column1_2"); //for second row of column 1
etc.
```

Hope this helps.