# Readable output from Oracle procedure that returns a cursor in JMeter

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter, cursor, procedure

I have a procedure that takes in one VARCHAR parameter and returns an OUT CURSOR which is a list, in this case 3 rows with 9 columns.

My current JDBC Request:

```
CALL foo.bar.procedure('123456', ?)
```

- Query type: Callable Statement
- Parameter values: OUT
- Parameter types: OUT -10
- Variable names: outList
- Result variable name: resultList (this is always null, does it mean that the result is empty?)
- Handle ResultSet: Store as Object

Response data:

```
-1 updates.
Output variables by position:
[1] oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@21512d0b
```

outList is now `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@21512d0b`

I've tried getting some information from outList in a BeanShell sampler like is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969792/how-to-get-object-result-set-from-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter) but I haven't been able to get anything from it except just the ResultSet object id.

I'm new to calling procedures through Jmeter, View Result Tree doesn't seem to show me any result data and I've been going back and forth with the SQL Query and the parameter values, trying to fix it, but I always have the same trouble with the output.

I've also tried something like this with similar settings:

```
DECLARE
    refCursor sys_refcursor;
    Type MyRec Is Record (
       v1    varchar2(
       v2    varchar2(50),
       ...
       v13    varchar2(10));
   rec MyRec;   
BEGIN
    foo.bar.procedure('123456',refCursor);
    LOOP
        FETCH refCursor INTO rec;
        EXIT WHEN refCursor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(
         rec.v1||','||
         rec.v2||','||
         ...
         rec.v13);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Am I calling the procedure correctly or is something missing in the JDBC Request settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by moving away from JDBC Request sampler and used the BeanShell Sampler instead.

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;

ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
CallableStatement stmt;

// "myConnConfigName" is the 'JDBC Connection Configuration' variable name
Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("myConnConfigName");

try {
    stmt = conn.prepareCall("CALL foo.bar.procedure(?,?)");
    stmt.setString(1, "123456");
    stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    stmt.executeUpdate();

    rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(2);

    while (rs.next()) {
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        log.info("ColumnCount:" + rsmd.getColumnCount().toString());
        log.info("RowNo:" + rs.getRow().toString());

        // TODO: Store data.
        //       Loop through columns with rs.getString(i);
    }
}
catch(Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error message: ", ex);
    throw ex;
}
finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        stmt.close();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your request
2. Extract the "interesting" values from the `OracleResultSetImpl` as per [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) article, something like:

   ```
   import java.sql.ResultSet

   ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)vars.getObject('outList')

   while (rs.next()) {            
       vars.put('column_1_row_1_value`, rs.getString(0)) 
       ///...
   }
   ```

See [JDBC Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/) and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: I didn't get this to work with the JDBC Request sampler, I always got the error "Closed Statement: next".
I solved my problem by moving away from the JDBC Request sampler and calling the procedure from a BeanShell Sampler and then using your solution to store the output. Will post my solution soon.
Thank you Dmitri

Comment: Could you please post what you did with result set, I am looking for such kind of answer, I am using beanshell sampler to trigger my query. Looking for fetching the result.